# How to pass multiple parameters to a onclick event binded via javascript variable

Tags: javascript

Iam trying to create a button with onclick event with 2 parameters that should be passed during loop. Iam able to pass variables and it is showing up on inspect element., but onclicking the button., it is giving an error 'unexpected end of input'. I passed multiple parameters as obj. Its returning [object object]. I tried stringify. But on button click., its giving unexpected end of input.

All I need is when clicking "buy" button., i need to retreive id, username of the table row. can u help me where I have done wrong. [`[code here][1]`](https://plnkr.co/edit/hRRy93COHxNY0EpiYgwD?p=preview)

Comment: First of all, put your script in the body container. Then check lines 25 and 26.

Comment: tq... updated code in plunker... and I noticed button was unable to access scope of testobj.. updated code... but still getting unexpected identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just **swapped " " with ' '** in the following line and it seems to be working fine.

```
var addBtn = item.status == "New" ? "<button id='buy-" + item.name + "' onClick='buyPet(" + JSON.stringify(buyTestobj) + ")' >Buy</button>" : item.status;
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Tq... A simple change I was not able to notice.. script in single quotes and HTML in double quotes... which strikes now.. tq

Comment: Hi @shabarinath ,Glad to know that it helped . I hope you won't mind giving it an upvote as well :) .

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go this way but instead put a container with a button in the html, find the container/button and set it up with the id and onclick event (more of unobtrusive approach). Now regarding your question just pass an object containing whatever you need.

Comment: Hi, thank for inputs. However I have tried passing it as object. But on button click., it is unable to pass params as it returns [object object]. tired parsing. But no luck. I have updated plunker. can you please check